How to make PHP mailer work in my React app
I am trying to use PHP mailer in my React application because I have to deploy it on over afterward. I know it would be better to use Express but I have to use PHP :).
So that is the solution I thought of for the contact form.
I am encountering an issue. After trying to send an email to check if the server works the console returns: POST http://localhost:3000/server.php 404 (Not Found)
And I checked the path to my server.php file so I really don't know what the problem is.
I have been searching for hours now and I can't find a solution ..
Any help would be truly appreciated.
Here is my form component :

import React, { useState } from 'react';

function ContactForm() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    subject: '',
    message: ''
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    try {
      const response = await fetch('./server.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });
  
      if (response.ok) {
        alert('Email sent successfully!');
        // You can redirect the user or perform any other action here
      } else {
        alert('Error sending email!');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending email:', error);
      alert('Error sending email!');
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={formData.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
          required
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Email:
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={formData.email}
          onChange={handleChange}
          required
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Subject:
        <input
          type="text"
          name="subject"
          value={formData.subject}
          onChange={handleChange}
          required
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Message:
        <textarea
          name="message"
          value={formData.message}
          onChange={handleChange}
          required
        />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default ContactForm;

And here is my server.php file :
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
    $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
    $subject = htmlentities($_POST['subject']);
    $message = htmlentities($_POST['message']);

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'MYEMAILADRESS';
    $mail->Password = 'PASSWORD';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress('MYEMAILADRESS');
    $mail->Subject = ("$email ($subject)");
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->send();

    header("Location: ./server.php");}
?>

Here is a look at my folder:
(the Form component is located at: src/assets/Components/Form.js)
(server.php is in the public folder)
(phpmailer directory is in the src dir.)


I tried changing paths and checking for Apache versions, I also checked several tutorials but nothing worked for me.

This maybe a dumb reply on my part but does your PHP server run on port 3000? It would appear to me that your await fetch('./server.php', should be pointing at your PHP LAMP server, instead is trying to run it within node env.
